# JavaFX 17 Gluon on RaspberryPi 4 will not draw to second monitor

Tags: java, javafx, raspberry-pi4, gluon

I'm trying to write an application that uses both monitors hooked up to a RaspberryPi 4 in JavaFX.  I've tried existing demo code from both Gluon and other similar sources.

I'm using 64-bit beta OS from here:
https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_arm64/images/raspios_arm64-2021-04-09/

The Raspberry Pi4 is new with two 1920x1080 monitors hooked up.

raspi-config is set to boot to console (no GUI).

Java was installed using:

```
    sudo apt install default-jdk
```

I can see prompts and boot messages on both monitors.

I'm using Gluon's "JavaFX Linux AArch64 SDK + Monocle" v17 from here: https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/

My demo code is here:  https://github.com/maehem/JavaFXDualScreenDemo

According to the demos, I should be able to create two "Stage" objects and each renders to their own screen.

When I run these demos, I get both Stages rendering to the primary monitor only. At startup, I can see the red colored grid render for half a second and then covered over by the green colored grid.   The second monitor goes blank upon startup and nothing is ever rendered on it.

My /boot/config.txt settings:

```
# Enable DRM VC4 V3D drive
max_framebuffers=2
arm_64bit=1
gpu_mem=512
#hdmi_force_hotplug:0=1
#hdmi_force_hotplug:1=1
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
```

Things I've tried:
I've tried the 'hdmi_force_hotplug' option with both monitors with no better result.

Update:
I got a second Pi4 and installed as my notes show here.   Same result, both render on same screen:

```
Install RaspiOS:
http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspios_arm64/images/

/boot/config.txt  (make sure you are using ‘fkms’ )
# Enable DRM VC4 V3D drive
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2
arm_64bit=1
gpu_mem=512

sudo apt install default-jdk
 java -version

Download: https://gluonhq.com/download/javafx-17-ea-sdk-linux-aarch64/
Get Monocle edition!
sudo mv javafx-sdk-17.zip /opt
cd /opt
sudo unzip javafx-sdk-17.zip

vi .bashrc 
    ==>   export ENABLE_GLUON_COMMERCIAL_EXTENSIONS=true
```

Here is the log at run time. We can clearly see that Java found two Screen objects.

```
./run-hello 
Failed to open initctl fifo: Permission denied
Failed to talk to init daemon.
Prism pipeline init order: es2 sw 
Using Double Precision Marlin Rasterizer
Using dirty region optimizations
Not using texture mask for primitives
Not forcing power of 2 sizes for textures
Using hardware CLAMP_TO_ZERO mode
Opting in for HiDPI pixel scaling
Prism pipeline name = com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
Loading ES2 native library ... prism_es2_monocle
    succeeded.
GLFactory using com.sun.prism.es2.MonocleGLFactory
[GluonDRM] use GPU at /dev/dri/card1 and display id -1
S0 NOT defined: 
Master set for 9: 0
[GluonDRM] We have 2 connectors
[GluonDRM] mode[0]: 1920x1080
[GluonDRM] mode[1]: 1920x1080
[GluonDRM] mode[2]: 1920x1080i
[GluonDRM] mode[3]: 1920x1080i
[GluonDRM] mode[4]: 1920x1080
[GluonDRM] mode[5]: 1920x1080
[GluonDRM] mode[6]: 1280x720
[GluonDRM] mode[7]: 1280x720
[GluonDRM] mode[8]: 1024x768
[GluonDRM] mode[9]: 1440x480i
[GluonDRM] mode[10]: 800x600
[GluonDRM] mode[11]: 800x600
[GluonDRM] mode[12]: 720x480
[GluonDRM] mode[13]: 720x480
[GluonDRM] mode[14]: 720x480i
[GluonDRM] mode[15]: 720x480i
[GluonDRM] mode[16]: 640x480
[GluonDRM] mode[17]: 640x480
[GluonDRM] ID for connector[0] = 89, width = 1920 and height = 1080
[GluonDRM] Height was 0 and is now 1080
[GluonDRM] mode[0]: 1920x1080
[GluonDRM] mode[1]: 1920x1080
[GluonDRM] mode[2]: 1920x1080i
[GluonDRM] mode[3]: 1920x1080i
[GluonDRM] mode[4]: 1920x1080
[GluonDRM] mode[5]: 1920x1080i
[GluonDRM] mode[6]: 1600x1200
[GluonDRM] mode[7]: 1680x1050
[GluonDRM] mode[8]: 1400x1050
[GluonDRM] mode[9]: 1600x900
[GluonDRM] mode[10]: 1280x1024
[GluonDRM] mode[11]: 1280x1024
[GluonDRM] mode[12]: 1440x900
[GluonDRM] mode[13]: 1280x960
[GluonDRM] mode[14]: 1280x800
[GluonDRM] mode[15]: 1152x864
[GluonDRM] mode[16]: 1280x720
[GluonDRM] mode[17]: 1280x720
[GluonDRM] mode[18]: 1280x720
[GluonDRM] mode[19]: 1440x576
[GluonDRM] mode[20]: 1024x768
[GluonDRM] mode[21]: 1024x768
[GluonDRM] mode[22]: 1024x768
[GluonDRM] mode[23]: 1440x480
[GluonDRM] mode[24]: 1440x480
[GluonDRM] mode[25]: 832x624
[GluonDRM] mode[26]: 800x600
[GluonDRM] mode[27]: 800x600
[GluonDRM] mode[28]: 800x600
[GluonDRM] mode[29]: 800x600
[GluonDRM] mode[30]: 720x576
[GluonDRM] mode[31]: 720x576i
[GluonDRM] mode[32]: 720x480
[GluonDRM] mode[33]: 720x480
[GluonDRM] mode[34]: 720x480i
[GluonDRM] mode[35]: 720x480i
[GluonDRM] mode[36]: 640x480
[GluonDRM] mode[37]: 640x480
[GluonDRM] mode[38]: 640x480
[GluonDRM] mode[39]: 640x480
[GluonDRM] mode[40]: 640x480
[GluonDRM] mode[41]: 720x400
[GluonDRM] mode[42]: 720x240
[GluonDRM] mode[43]: 720x240
[GluonDRM] ID for connector[1] = 153, width = 1920 and height = 1080
Master dropped: 0
eglinit ok 
eglbind ok 
eglCreateWindowSurface called
(X) Got class = class com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
Initialized prism pipeline: com.sun.prism.es2.ES2Pipeline
requested number of screens, return 2
[GluonDRM] getWidth asked, return 1920
[GluonDRM] doGetHeight asked, vs = 0, fbw = 3840, fbh = 1080
[GluonDRM] getWidth asked, return 1920
[GluonDRM] doGetHeight asked, vs = 0, fbw = 3840, fbh = 1080
Maximum supported texture size: 4096
Non power of two texture support = true
Maximum number of vertex attributes = 16
Maximum number of uniform vertex components = 16384
Maximum number of uniform fragment components = 16384
Maximum number of varying components = 64
Maximum number of texture units usable in a vertex shader = 16
Maximum number of texture units usable in a fragment shader = 16
Graphics Vendor: Broadcom
       Renderer: V3D 4.2
        Version: OpenGL ES 3.1 Mesa 19.3.2
 vsync: true vpipe: true
Screen bounds: Rectangle2D [minX = 0.0, minY=0.0, maxX=1920.0, maxY=1080.0, width=1920.0, height=1080.0]
Number of screens found: 2
Parsing screen: javafx.stage.Screen@a1603782 bounds:Rectangle2D [minX = 0.0, minY=0.0, maxX=1920.0, maxY=1080.0, width=1920.0, height=1080.0] visualBounds:Rectangle2D [minX = 0.0, minY=0.0, maxX=1920.0, maxY=1080.0, width=1920.0, height=1080.0] dpi:96.0 outputScale:(1.0,1.0)
Parsing screen: javafx.stage.Screen@ec83c09b bounds:Rectangle2D [minX = 1920.0, minY=0.0, maxX=3840.0, maxY=1080.0, width=1920.0, height=1080.0] visualBounds:Rectangle2D [minX = 1920.0, minY=0.0, maxX=3840.0, maxY=1080.0, width=1920.0, height=1080.0] dpi:96.0 outputScale:(1.0,1.0)
ES2ResourceFactory: Prism - createStockShader: Solid_Color.frag
ES2ResourceFactory: Prism - createStockShader: DrawPgram_Color.frag
ES2ResourceFactory: Prism - createStockShader: Solid_TextureFirstPassLCD.frag
ES2ResourceFactory: Prism - createStockShader: Solid_TextureSecondPassLCD.frag
ES2ResourceFactory: Prism - createStockShader: Solid_TextureRGB.frag
[GluonDRM] realswapbuffer called
Gluon Commercial Features unlocked
[GluonDRM] eglSwapBuffers ok
[GluonDRM] realswapbuffer called
[GluonDRM] eglSwapBuffers ok
^C[GluonDRM] realswapbuffer called
QuantumRenderer: shutdown
[GluonDRM] eglSwapBuffers ok
```

Comment: Your project works for me using Raspberry Pi 4 64 bits + 2 HDMI monitors 1920x1080, same config.txt settings. I see each stage in each monitor.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback Jose.   I did buy a second Pi 4 and will repeat my setup  and see if there is any difference. BTW, I really enjoyed your stream [ https://www.twitch.tv/videos/1048684120  ] last week regarding JavaFX on two monitors.

Comment: Maybe you want to check out this new sample: https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/pull/113. Follow the Readme instructions, and once you have it working in one monitor, add your main class, and change the mainClass in the pom. That's what I did to test it yesterday.

Comment: Jose, I attempted to use your latest 'pull/113' code as a starting point but I ran into other technical issues that prevent me from using the Gluon with maven for now.  I am on a OS X laptop (which does not seem to support cross compile, "Error: We currently can't compile to aarch64-linux-linux when running on x86_64-apple-darwin" ).   I don't have a native Linux OS machine at the moment and the demos don't seem to want to compile directly on the RaspberryPi (Error: libprism_sw.so: cannot open shared object file ). I will shelve this for a while until I make progress on my main project.

Comment: I did finally get a dual screen solution to work, but the big difference is that on my system, the Stage has a boundary that includes both monitors (i.e width: 2x1920 = 3840).  So I just used the stage provided by the start method.  Things that were at an LayoutX higher than 1920 appeared on the second monitor.  I'd really like to understand why others are able to use multiple Stages that are associated with the enumerated screens as that seems like a nifty feature when screens are different sizes.

Comment: There is one single framebuffer that takes the whole space available (`fbw = 3840, fbh = 1080`). However, your screens should accommodate the existing monitors found with bounds `minX = 0.0, minY=0.0, maxX=1920.0, maxY=1080.0` and `minX = 1920.0, minY=0.0, maxX=3840.0, maxY=1080.0`, and you should be able to create at least two stages, one at each screen. As I mentioned before, that works for me with your project and the exact same setup. In theory, the `primaryStage` should be bound to the primary screen.

Comment: Assuming that creating a new Stage would place it in the one single framebuffer available, then it appears to me that the Stage.setX() command is being ignored since we try to assign the X value to the beginning of the next "screen" (1920) yet the new Stage remains at X=0 of the framebuffer space.

Comment: That's your case only, it works fine for me. Are you using the latest 17-ea+11? btw, there is a new 17-ea+12, can you try it out? https://gluonhq.com/products/javafx/#ea

Comment: Jose,  Yes. was using 17-ea+11,  just installed 17-ea+12 and same result.  Is it possible there is some system level setting I'm missing somewhere?  When you run without the Window system, are you setting that in the raspi-config ==> boot-to-command-line like I am?

Comment: Yes, command line only. No system level settings required. Do you have only the two HDMI monitors plugged (no DSI display plugged)?

Comment: No DSI.  Two HDMI monitors on the HDMI connectors.  The only difference between them is that one is a computer monitor (with HDMI) and the other is a Television (with HDMI). Make me wonder if it's a HDCP related issue?  I haven't worked in that realm over a decade, but its something I've wondered about regarding this.